# Why is Textmate treating *.rb files as PlainText

Tags: ruby, textmate

Been using Textmate 2 for ages.   Usually keep it on the nightly builds.  A couple of weeks ago it started sporadically treating all my *.rb files as plaintext. And as of the latest release build - it treats all my *.rb files as Plaintext. :(

I've tried:

- Turning off all the syntax highlighters, restarting TM and reinstalling them
- Uninstalling TM; reinstalling the App
- Using only the actual releases, instead of nightly builds

After uninstalling all language packs, it correctly asks to install coffeescript, javascript, json, etc when I open those files.  However, it does *not* ask for a *.rb file.

I've searched the TM mailing list and found nothing similar.

*.rake, *.rbx and all the other file types listed in the Ruby Language pack are recognized as ruby.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "uninstall" do you mean you've removed things in `Library/Application Support` as well? There's a lot of stuff that's stashed in there that persists.

Comment: Sentence two: "Usually keep it on the nighly builds.". And you wonder why it does not work?

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that Cort3z... however, usually nightly builds are great -- and I did mention switching to the public releases before asking the Internet :)

Comment: Good thought @tadman -- I have not done that yet.  I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

When you open a file and manually change the file type via the status bar then TextMate 2 will remember this binding (for all files using same extension) in `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Global.tmProperties`.

There are a few options to undo a stored file type binding:

1. Open a `*.rb` file and select *Ruby* via the status bar.
2. Edit `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Global.tmProperties` to remove anything that sets `fileType` for `*.rb`. Such entry would look like:

   ```
   [ *.rb ]
   fileType = text.plain
   ```
3. Delete `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Global.tmProperties`.

Comment: No need to delete the whole Global.tmProperties file.  Just remved the like where *.rb is referenced, restart and good to go.

Answer (score 1):

- Quit TextMate
- Remove /Library/Application Support/TextMate
- Remove ~/Library/Application Support/TextMate
- Launch TextMate
- Open a *.rb file
- Profit!